# Text ignores bottom padding, draws next line regardless

Tags: css, text, overflow, padding

Apparently my post page decided to have mind on it's own and refused to work as it should.

The text (span) stored inside box (div) draws next line despite max height being set to maximum of 6 lines + padding.

As seen here:

[image]

So, obviously I don't have any solution to it, here's code:

```
            <div class = "post">
                <div class = "post-title">Lorem ipsum dolor amet</div>
                <div class = "post-content"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
                <div class = "post-footer"><span class = "post-date">2017.02.07</span><span class = "post-author">- J.</span></div>
            </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.post-content
{
    max-height: 128px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: rgb( 81, 85, 88 );
}

.post-content span
{
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2rm969es/

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle? looks like `.post-footer` is positioned absolute and hides your content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an explicit line-height seems to work for me:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNjxRW

```
line-height: 20px;
```

Are you trying to have the 10px of padding also appear above the footer?

Comment: No, the padding is set inside span, it's mean to be at top and bottom of bounds.

Comment: You may need to contain the lower padding in the footer as padding in the span won't hide the content that would be displayed within the padding area.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else who has or will have this issue in the future - put padding on footer and title, it won't be as tidy as you might've wished it to be - but it'll get rid of annoying 'draw over text' thing.